# Who is at fault if drink on desktop ruins electronics?

Tags: relationships, germany, damage

My colleague came to me and, while we were talking about a project, he accidentally spilt my 1.5l mineral water directly on my two personal cell phones and some papers. Not a big deal, I jokingly say that if they broke he could buy me new ones. And that's made him mad. Like: *it's your fault, you're not allowed to leave open bottles on desk, next time take a bit more care... etc.*

This took place in Germany.

It's my first job in this country and I'm not sure if I should raise it with my manager or leave as it is? By the way, this colleague is my mentor; from this point of view I don't want to break our relationship. However, I do feel a little oppressed.

Comment: Simple there is a work guideline on drinks on the desktop or not.  It is rare but some environments do have rule against drinks on the desktop.  Either way he should have said sorry and not gotten mad.

Comment: are they broken or not?

Comment: You have learned something valuable - your colleague and mentor has a markedly different sense of humour from you. Take that, and move on.

Comment: You said you said jokingly, but were you actually joking? Maybe you just need to clarify with your colleague that it wasn't really serious.

Comment: If there is no explicit written rule saying you can't or you haven't been made aware of that rule then I think your or his insurance covers damage for that.

Comment: I would not worry about it, but I would have told him straight away at the time that there is no need to be rude, and if he was rude and I checked the phones and they were broken I'd make him pay for it in one way or another.

Comment: This is for a judge to decide. Closed as legal question.

Comment: If you think it was "joking" then it was actually "passive aggressive."

Answer (score 5):

I have offices in Frankfurt.  There are no "extra special" rules that I know of in Germany.  We are tech and have open cups laying everywhere with water, soda, and whatever.

If a coworker spills something on your phone this is a tricky subject no matter if they are a superior or not.  You have to take the following into account:

- what was the liquid in.  If it was in something that could spill easily and was tall that really make it more of your fault.
- where was the liquid.  If it was right by the keyboard and someone is helpinng you, again that is more your fault.
- where were the electronics.  If the phone is right next to the drink, again stupid.
- what was the action of the coworker.  If the coworker were throwing a ball and knocked it over this is much different from him hitting it with his elbow as he tries to show you something.

So there are degrees of fault with things like this.  If it is even close to 50% it is really best for you to take full responsibility in a work environment.  Your coworker response could have been warranted if you had a really easy situation for your electronics to get damaged and you looked at him like a dufus after he hit your drink.

**Update:** As a good comment remarks the degree of fault will probably come down to your word against your mentor's.  Unless this incident was captured via video I wouldn't touch it.  Who would your HR believe even if you were completely telling the truth and right - the new guy or the mentor?

Moral of the story here.  Take care of your own crap.  Put your personal electronics away.  If it is company electronics make sure they don't have eat at desk rules.  Assume responsibility for accidents that you encouraged.

Comment: If its not explicitly disallowed then the fact that hes your coworker doesn't change the fact that if he breaks it, either he or his insurance pays for it.

Comment: @Magisch - that simply isn't true.  If it were true every time I had a broken phone I would set up 50 very tall water bottles on my desk with my phone in the middle and let my clumsy coworkers work their magic.  Second he pays for what?  Real cost or what it was worth?  And third who is enforcing that coworker pays for it?  In the US it is really a civil matter.

Comment: in germany its not. If someone breaks your stuff, you are entitled to have them pay for it. Unless its gross neglegience. But the accused person has to prove that.

Comment: @Magisch - who makes you pay in Germany?  So I could come to work one day and Bob can say I broke his phone and the German police are going to make me pay him on the spot unless I have witness testimony?   I don't really get where you are coming from.  And what insurance would cover this in Germany?  I am in Germany a lot and I don't have clumsy insurance.

Comment: As far as I've witnessed so far, once a guy broke part of my bike by accident, and all I had to do was fill out a form for his insurance and they handled the rest.

Comment: It seems that in Germany (most/everyone) has something called 'Haftpflichtversicherung' which is designed to cover this sort of damage. http://www.howtogermany.com/pages/insurance.html. It seems like insurance for clumsiness so the OP could say Bob broke my phone and its value is 500 Euro and it would be down to Bob to then contest this version of events or let his insurance pay. Please correct me if this isn't what you're referring to.

Comment: @Magisch thats very different to accidentally damaging something on someones desk - there are no laws unilaterally requiring someone to pay in the event they accidentally damage something, although you could pursue the issue through the courts if you wish.  This is what insurance companies would do in vehicular accidents if the other side refused to pay out - they would take the issue to court.  In this instance, its up to the good will of the other person to pay out, or the person suffering the loss has to press the issue in court.

Comment: @Moo - Exactly.  Haftpflichtversicherung is just liability insurance and covers the same protocols that we are used to in the states on auto accidents/claims.  There is no magic fairy that will make this person's insurance claim unless it was proved he was at fault.  You would have similar duties to do when going to civil court in the US.  Also if the person did not have Haftpflichtversicherung then you would be basically going to court.  There is no way knocking a drink over on a desk is the other person's sole fault unless they agree to it.

Comment: "talking about project he accidentally spill" is clearly not throwing a ball.  What was the liquid "1.5L mineral water".  The water is not going to land on a phone if the phone was not by the water.

Comment: @blankip: Breaking someone's stuff is harmless. Lying about breaking someone's stuff can be criminal. Even if there is no evidence, your HR will know "we have two guys here; one of them has been lying in a way that he should be fired for it. Unfortunately we cannot prove which one". That's not a good situation.

Comment: @gnasher729 - absolutely that is why I am proposing take care of your own electronics and take blame in most cases - unless someone was doing something really stupid or if they did it on  purpose.  Who does HR believe, the new guy or his mentor?  So even if he is right, he could be in essence blackballed early in his career because of a phone incident.  I will update my answer better.

Answer (score 1):

You're not in position of force, there.

1. he's above you, kind of. So if he's wrong, he's right anyways.
2. you were not cautious by leaving an open bottle next to brittle electronic parts. Allowed or not. I killed a keyboard by spilling tea over it - fortunately, it was not a laptop's keyboard, but still. I took the risk. And if someone else had spilled my own tea over my keyboard, I still would have been guilty. If there is no risk, there is no accident.

It's even worse in Germany, they are rather touchy about safety at work. But everywhere in the world, I'd expect you to assume the risks you've taken.

Comment: Excuse me, but this is in Germany. Might = right was abolished 70 years ago.

Comment: yeah. Safety über alles. I worked there for a few months, they don't laugh with people taking risks. Took me some time to adapt, but at the end of the day, I tend to believe THEY are right.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z Unless you have specific equipment which could damage you if its shorts, this is unrelated to work safety. If there was no policy in the company prohibiting this, he will be required to pay in full for any necessary repairs to the damaged items. He or his insurance.

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, this is simple really. **He broke it, he pays for it.** End of discussion.

Details:

Everybody in Germany has an insurance called "Haftpflichtversicherung" that pays for anything you accidentally damaged. It's very inexpensive. So what really happens is you both sit together and fill out his insurance's form for such matters. Then the insurance pays for your damages. He will not lose a single cent over this. The insurance will not even raise it's rates over a single common incident like this.

Workplace regulations do not play into this for everyday life. The insurance will not care. However, you could still get into trouble with your company. After all, it could have been their precious equipment that got damaged, instead of your phones. But that's an independent case. You could have gotten in trouble for it even if the spill missed your phones by a mile.

You may want to remind him of these matters, maybe he does not know either. He probably *has* an insurance, he just does not know it works this way. He probably got mad at the thought of having to pay hundreds of euros just because of a clumsy split-second move. He does not. Chances are, his insurance covers it and there is no reason to get mad at all.

Comment: This is too easy to say.  He may think the coworker was negligent.  Haftpflichtversicherung does not cover breaking things when their was negligence on the other party.  It is not that simple.  First you are assuming he is going to agree to fill this out.  Second you are assuming that this person will not have hostility over the OP.  It isn't a purely legal question it is a question of the workplace.  Also you cannot be sure that he won't have to pay some sort of premium for the incident or incur higher rates.

Comment: It's not negligent to have an open water bottle on the same desk as your electronics. Now, if he secretly greased his phone and the coworker dropped it, *that* would be negligence. Or it might be unclear if the coworker bumped into another who bumped the table where the bottle spilled it's contents. But one person spilling water over another persons electronics? That's nothing an insurance will look at twice at. That's their daily business.

Comment: I would say it is negligent to have water next to your phone and keyboard - almost gross negligence.  If this went to civil trial in the US the phone owner would lose well more than they would win, if they ever won.  Again if the person sits down and fills out form then great you got your phone back - but maybe ruined your career - and that is if they filled out the form with you.

Comment: "Everybody in Germany has an insurance called *Haftpflichtversicherung*": With [some exceptions](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftpflichtversicherung#Typische_Pflichthaftpflichtversicherungen), this is not mandatory, right?

Comment: Haftpflichtversicherung covers _exactly_ breaking things through negligence. If it's not your fault, you don't have to pay, and therefore your insurance doesn't pay. If it is your fault, through negligence, then you have to pay, so your insurance has to pay. Different if it is your fault through gross negligence or by damaging something intentionally.

Comment: ... and if your small children (say four year old) break something, your insurance will ask you if you were negligent by not watching them properly. The correct answer is YES. If you were negligent, it's your fault, and the insurance pays. If you were not negligent, and your four old broke something even though you watched him carefully, tough luck for the person whose property was broken.

Comment: @unor you are correct, it's not mandatory. But it would be stupid beyond belief to not have one. I will assume people in Germany have upwards of one brain cell. I don't know anyone who'd think of not having one.

Comment: @blankip I don't know about US courts. No German court I know of has ever ruled it negligent to have your cell phone on the same desk as an open bottle of water or cup of coffee. Feel free to prove me wrong, I'm not a lawyer, just a German who constantly has his phone on the same desk as his coffee and feels pretty safe about it.

Comment: @nvoigt I doubt it is negligent legally in the US either.  I haven't seen anyone at any of my workplaces that keeps their coffee, water, etc. on a separate desk.